# Batch copying to all folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, copying, file-copying, file-moving

I need to batch copy two folders, let's call them A and B, from `F:\Sourcefolder\` to `F:\destinationfolder` subfolders (not to destination folder itself).

Now I know when batch copying file (`file.exe` for example) it is supposed to look something like this

```
for /r "F:\destinationfolder" %%i in (.) do @copy "F:\Sourcefolder\file.exe" "%i"
```

In each of those subfolders there is a lot of files. After copying A and B folders to all subfolders, I would like to move all files within the subfolders to folder A within their folder. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

the XCOPY command is designed for folder copy, `FOR /D` will list level1 folders:

```
for /d %%a in ("F:\destinationfolder\*") do (
    XCOPY "F:\Sourcefolder\A\*" "%%~fa" /s /i
    XCOPY "F:\Sourcefolder\B\*" "%%~fa" /s /i
)
```

for recursive copy (all subfolders):

```
for /r /d "F:\destinationfolder\" %%a in (*) do (
    XCOPY "F:\Sourcefolder\A\*" "%%~fa" /s /i
    XCOPY "F:\Sourcefolder\B\*" "%%~fa" /s /i
)
```

`FOR /R` will not work properly if there's no wildcard in the brackets - `?` or `*`

[ROBOCOPY](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html),[XCOPY](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

Comment: `xcopy` is deprecated, use `robocopy` in new scripts.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, the second code will copy folder A and B to all of the subfolders of my destination folder?

Comment: @ĐurađStanković it should but I didn't test it (only the first script is tested)